# wlan connection stops working when ppp 3g connection is running

Tags: networking, ppp, wlan

I have ZTE MF669 modem and RTL8188eu wifi card.

My wifi address is fixed (192.168.1.14).

Modem gets address from 10.0.0.0/8 subnet.

My wlan connection stops working when I connect to 3G network. I tried with ping 192.168.1.14.

SSH (with putty) disconnects when modem is obtaining network parameters.

Modem connection works normally.

I can't troubleshoot this from console (this is headless system - no monitor, no keyboard).

**What is the problem?**

Comment: The problem is likely that the computer will route all traffic out of the 3G connection when it connects. I would attach a screen / keyboard to it before you try and do anything else as it would make things a whole lot easier.

Comment: I have 2 USB ports there. One is WiFi, other is 3G modem... I don't want to buy USB port replicator to solve this :)